# How to pass variable parameters to an XPages SSJS function?

Tags: xpages

If I have a function in SSJS and I want to pass one "firm" parameter and a list of others that can change, what's the best way to do that?  With some kind of hashMap or JSON or something else?

for example given something like:

myfunction( code:string, paramList:??) {
// do stuff here

}

Basically the function will create a document.  And sometimes I'll have certain fields I'll want to pass in right away and populate and other times I'll have different fields I will want to populate.

How would you pass them in and then parse out in the function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the arguments parameter... In JavaScript you are not required to define any of your parameters in the function block itself. So, for example, the following call:

```
myFunction(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4);
```

can legally be passed to the following function:

```
myFunction () {
  // do stuff here...
}
```

when I do this, I usually place a comment in the parens to indicate I am expecting variable arguments:

```
myFunction (/* I am expecting variable arguments to be passed here */) {
  // do stuff here...
}
```

Then, you can access those arguments like this:

```
myFunction (/* I am expecting variable arguments to be passed here */) {
  if (arguments.length == 0) {
    // naughty naughty, you were supposed to send me things...
    return null;
  }

  myExpectedFirstArgument = arguments[0];

  // maybe do something here with myExpectedFirstArgument
  var whatEvah:String = myExpectedFirstArgument + ":  "

  for (i=1;i<arguments.length;i++) {
    // now do something with the rest of the arguments, one 
    // at a time using arguments[i]
    whatEvah = whatEvah + " and " + arguments[i];
  }

  // peace.
  return whatEvah;
}
```

Wallah, variable arguments.

But, more to the point of your question, I don't think you need to actually send variable arguments, nor go through the hassle of creating actual JSON (which is really a string interpretation of a javascript object), just create and send the actual object then reference as an associative array to get your field names and field values:

```
var x = {};
x.fieldName1 = value1;
x.fieldName2 = value2;
// ... etc ...
```

then in your function, which now needs only two parameters:

```
myFunction(arg1, arg2) {
   // do whatever with arg1

   for (name in arg2) {
     // name is now "fieldName1" or "fieldName2"
     alert(name + ": " + x[name]);
   }

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy.  I really like creating the object first and passing that in.  I'll use that in other places as well now.

Answer (score 5):

I would do this with a JSON object as the second parameter...

```
function myfunction(code:String, data) {
   // do stuff here...
   var doc:NotesDocument = database.CreateDocument();
   if(data) {
      for (x in data) {
         doc.replaceItemValue(x, data[x]);
      }
   }
   // do more stuff
   doc.save(true, false);
}
```

Then you call the function like this:

```
nyfunction("somecode", {form:"SomeForm", subject:"Whatever",uname:@UserName()});
```

Happy coding.

/Newbs

Comment: Read through your example more after I posted mine below - I was thrown off by you saying a JSON object ... its not really a "JSON object", its a javascript object... JSON is a string representation of an object -- so essentially my and your answer are the same.

Comment: Thanks Henry!  This is really similar to Jeremy's answer.  You beat him but I like his part about creating the object first.  Kinda like a LotusScript TYPE it feels like.  So I'll mark his as the answer and will buy you a beer next time I see you.  Everyone wins!  :-)

Answer (score -3):

I don't think that is possible in SSJS. I think the best option you have is to pass a hashmap or your own (java) object. I think a custom java object would be the nicest option because you can define some 'structure' on how your function can process it. A hashmap can be easily extended but it is not easy if you have a lot of code that create a lot of different hashmap structures...

Comment: It is possible, variable arguments are possible in javascript.

Comment: In javascript: yes you can, but the question was about SSJS. And the answer given was in javascript. I tried it before in SSJS but I didn't got it working

Comment: SSJS and JavaScript are both based on ECMAScript - and the following works for me: XPages Code:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">

    <xp:this.resources>
        <xp:script
            src="/mulitpParms.jss"
            clientSide="false">
        </xp:script>
    </xp:this.resources>
    
    <xp:text value="#{javascript:outputMultipleParms('one', 'two', 'three');}" />

</xp:view>

SSJS Code:
function outputMultipleParms() {
 var output:string = "";
 for (i=0;i<arguments.length;i++) {
  output += arguments[i] + "-";
 }
 return output;
}