# I would like to print selected documents from a view

Tags: xpages

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to print selected documents in an simple xPages view.  I'm converting a legacy application.  Which used the following Lotus script code to print.  Thanks

```
Set db = session.CurrentDatabase
Set collection = db.UnprocessedDocuments
count = collection.count

If count = 0 Then
    Goto errSelectDocs
End If

Stop
For i = 1 To count
      '
    Set note = collection.GetnthDocument (i)

    Set Source2 = w.EditDocument( False, note )

    Set Source3 = w.ComposeDocument("","","mRecensement imp")
    Call Source3.print(1)
    Call Source3.close
    Call Source2.close


      '----------------------------------

nextdocument:        

Next
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to answer here rather the following up in the comments of the Simon answer.
so ok.  We're saying build a new page with a repeat control of the select documents.  and the question asker is saying, I THINK, that it seems wrong to do:
     doc:NotesDocument=database.getDocumentByID(rowData); 
     return doc.getItemValue("xxxx") for 30 + items

right.  You don't want to do that.  should work.  But icky to do.

Probably what I would do is create a SSJS function to pass rowData into.  In that function build an array.  Load the document once...  put all the items into the array and pass them back to the page with the repeat control.

Probably what you do then is have a panel and use either a dataContext or objectData that's bound to the panel.  Inside the panel is your page and fields.  Those fields just read from the dataContext or objectData. so you're only getting the document once.  I guess you could even use just a scoped variable though I don't think there's an event to call code on each row.  So you'd need to hack it into the first field maybe or something.
But that's what you want.  I previously asked a question on StackOver flow about returning multiple parameters like this:  [How to pass variable parameters to an XPages SSJS function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9897636/how-to-pass-variable-parameters-to-an-xpages-ssjs-function)

Maybe that's helpful.

Comment: I smell another notesin9. :)

Comment: Very helpful, I will try this next week.  Thanks Simon, your 'icky' solution with recycle works well.  But I want to eliminate so many round trips for data

Comment: Finally I loaded the data once into a data bean.  Then simply referenced the other fields using EL.  Thanks Simon and David.

Answer (score 0):

Someone might come up with a better solution but one option is this.

First have your viewPanel on your first XPage. Select your documents and click a button. The code would do this.

```
var viewPanel = getComponent("viewPanel1");
sessionScope.documentIDs = viewPanel.getSelectedIds();
```

You then hand it off to another XPage which has a repeat control of the print structure for a document. It reads the document ID's and creates the page. Then just use the normal print command after loading.

```
window.print();
```

Comment: Hmmm if create a repeat :<xp:repeat id="repeat1" rows="30"
  value="#{sessionScope.documentIDs}" var="rowData">
 <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1"><xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript: 
var doc:NotesDocument=database.getDocumentByID(rowData);
return doc.getItemValue("dossier");}]]></xp:this.value></xp:text>
 <xp:br></xp:br>  This works but can I put a NotesDocument in viewScope as I have about 30 fields to print

Comment: I don't know why you want to put a notesdocument object in viewScope.  First. you don't want to put any notes objects in scope. You can put an array of UNID's in scope and just repeat from that.  Not sure what I'm missing...

Comment: It just does not seem efficient to repeat doc:NotesDocument=database.getDocumentByID(rowData); return doc.getItemValue("xxxx") for 30 + items.  I'm wondering if there's a better way.  It'S probably me that is missing something :)

Comment: You recycle the documents as you go through the loop. The other option is to have a view with the fields you want to print. You won't be able to print RT fields that way though.

Comment: It's a little hard for me to follow this as the code is in comments and all that.  You're saying for EACH field you're doing: